# Laravel 8 issue with controller inside subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, controller, namespaces

I have laravel 8 project and I am facing issue with controller which is in subfolder.

I have DashboardController located in /app/Http/Controllers/Dashboard. In my web.php I have:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\DashboardController;
Route::get('dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'dashboardView']);
```

DashboardController has this namespace:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard;
```

I have tried uncomment $namespace variable in RouteServiceProvider.php. Also I have added:

```
 ->namespace($this->namespace);
```

in boot() method. But with no luck. I got this error:

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\Controller' not found"
```

When I have DashboardController in laravel controller folder, everything works well. Also interesting is LoginController. It is in Auth subfolder (Controllers/Auth) and this controller works from subfolder.

Reason why I want to move controller into subfolder(s) is better organisation of files.

Is anybody here, who can help me figure out this issue? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that class file you are referencing `Controller`; most likely `extends Controller` on the class definition. There is no class named `Controller` in that namespace you have declared, `App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard`. You are most likely trying to reference `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` which means you will need a `use` statement for that or referencing it by its FQCN, Fully Qualified Class Name.

Comment: Lagbox thank you very much!!! It works now. I totally did not notice missing Controller use statement.